# Как лучше работать со строковым файлом в Java

Tags: java

Вопрос в том, что есть файл(обычный .txt), в этом файл имеет вид 10 строк и два столбца в каждом столбце номера. Необходимо как то работать с эти файлом, а то есть считать данные и по номеру из первого столбца выводить данные со второго столбца. Как это сделать, использовать базу данных или sharedPreference или массивы? Подскажите пожалуйста. 
Вид файла который надо считать имеет вид:

- 000000001 0002
- 000000002 09809
- 000000003 0002
- 000000004 09809
  и т.д.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Зачем все так усложнять?

```
final File data = new File("file.txt");
LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(data)));
String line;
while((line = lnr.readLine()) != null)
{
    final String args[] = line.split("\t", -1);
    //parse params args[0], args[1]
    int id_1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int id_2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
}
```

Comment: А как мне их связать?. То есть я ввожу в на экране 000000003 ответ 0002.

Comment: в каком смысле связать? Вы хотите на один аргумент выводить совершенно другой, не сопоставимый по лейну? Если да, то составляем коллекцию Map<K, V> и вносим по ключу параметры args[1]. Если же нет, то вот вам рабочая функции парса параметров по лейну файла.

Comment: Может я не правильно как то объясняю, извините, смысл в том, что есть файл в нем есть информация. Допустим 00000003 и его значение 0002. Мне надо как то это все сохранить в массиве или еще в чем то , что бы я мог потом обратиться к числу 00000003 и получить его значение 0002.

Comment: не вопрос, делаем Map<K, V> где key - 00000003, а value - 0002, т.е. Map<Integer, Integer> data = new HashMap<>(); data.put(id_1, id_2); используем как, data.get(key) <- вернет параметр id_2. Учите java сударь

Comment: Спасибо, я обязательно с этим разберусь.

Answer (score -1):

Данный пример применим к Android. Может кому интересно будет решение моей проблемы. 
Я решил, что не буду сохранять данные всего файла в `Map`, а буду считывать файл в отдельном потоке, как только встречается требуемое значение поток вернет нам значение из второго столбца. Реализовал я все это в отдельном `AsyncTask` классе. Данный код протестировал, работает быстро и без глюков, количество строк около 2000 тысяч.

Создал класс `FindKeyAsyncTask` данный поток принимает `String` - искомое значение, и возвращает `String` -  результат.

```
public class FindKeyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

Context context;

public FindKeyAsyncTask(Context context) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    final String FILENAME = "data.db";

    String result = "";
    String str = "";

    try {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(context.openFileInput(FILENAME)));
        while ((str = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] array = str.split("\t");
            if (array[0].equals(params[0])){
                result=array[1];
                return result;
            }else {
                result = context.getString(R.string.f2_NotFound);
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return result;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    FindFragment.tv_amount.setText(result);
}
```

}